# npm publish package to tfs

Tags: git, npm, tfs

I am trying to publish a package to tfs using npm publish, but fail shown:

> npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 500

Open the npm-debug.log file, I found an url: http://192.168.34.182:8080/tfs/iGeoTeam/_packaging/NPMTEST/npm/registry/my-ng-module, `my-ng-module` is what I want to publish package.

Paste the url in browser, shown:

> {"success":"false","error":"BadGateway","reason":"无法连接到远程服务器"}

The reason means that: can not connect to remote server.

the ip is an internal network. I have try ping it and work well.

Anyone kown why? thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correctly [Set up your client's npmrc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/npm/npmrc) and have the permissions to publish the packages, refer to [Editing permissions for a feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/feeds/feed-permissions#edit-permissions).

Also check no any policy/firewall settings blocking the access.

If there are no any problems for above checking, then you can clean caches first then try logging in again (`npm login`) and retrying the publish (`npm publish`).

[Publish an npm package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/npm/publish) for your reference.